# Why does push_back or push_front invalidate a deque's iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, deque

As the title asks.

My understanding of a deque was that it allocated "blocks". I don't see how allocating more space invalidates iterators, and if anything, one would think that a deque's iterators would have more guarantees than a vector's, not less.

Comment: iirc, gcc's implementation of deque keeps an array of pointers to those blocks... If the array needs to be reallocated, then iterators might become invalid. Maybe that's the reason? I'm not sure... That at least explains why insertions to either ends invalidate iterators, but not references/pointers to elements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't specify how deque is implemented. It isn't required to allocate new space by allocating a new chunk and chaining it on to the previous ones, all that's required is that insertion at each end be amortized constant time.

So, while it's easy to see how to implement deque such that it gives the guarantee you want[*], that's not the only way to do it.

[*] Iterators have a reference to an element, plus a reference to the block it's in so that they can continue forward/back off the ends of the block when they reach them. Plus I suppose a reference to the deque itself, so that `operator+` can be constant-time as expected for random-access iterators -- following a chain of links from block to block isn't good enough.

Comment: deque isn't list, blocks are not chained!

Answer (score 15):

What's more interesting is that `push_back` and `push_front` will **not** invalidate any **references** to a deque's elements.  Only iterators are to be assumed invalid.

The standard, to my knowledge, doesn't state why.  However if an iterator were implemented that was aware of its immediate neighbors - as a list is - that iterator would become invalid if it pointed to an element that was both at the edge of the deque and the edge of a block.

Comment: Another reason i think is that the iterator could be implemented by keeping an index of an element. If something is inserted at the begin/end of the deque, that index is now not valid anymore (off-by-one), although any pointer/reference to that element it was pointing to is still valid, since no reallocation happened, of course). Same when we keep in index into an array of block-pointers (as i guessed in my comment on the question).

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420347/3903076) for an explanation of this based on a straightforward implementation.

Answer (score 7):

My guess. **push_back/push_front** can allocate a new memory block. A deque iterator must know when increment/decrement operator should jump into the next block. The implementation may store that information in iterator itself. Incrementing/decrementing an old iterator after **push_back/push_front** may not work as intended.

This code may or may not fail with run time error. On my Visual Studio it failed in debug mode but run to the conclusion in release mode. On Linux it caused segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int main() {
    std::deque<int> x(1), y(1);
    std::deque<int>::iterator iterx = x.begin();
    std::deque<int>::iterator itery = y.begin();

    for (int i=1; i<1000000; ++i) {
        x.push_back(i);
        y.push_back(i);
        ++iterx;
        ++itery;
        if(*iterx != *itery) {
            std::cout << "increment failed at " << i << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The key thing is not to make any assumptions just treat the iterator as if it will be invalidated.

Even if it works fine now, a later version of the compiler or the compiler for a different platform might come along and break your code. Alternatively, a colleague might come along and decide to turn your deque into a vector or linked list.

Answer (score 4):

An iterator is not just a reference to the data. It must know how to increment, etc.

In order to support random access, implementations will have a dynamic array of pointers to the chunks. The deque iterator will point into this dynamic array. When the deque grows, a new chunk might need to be allocated. The dynamic array will grow, invalidating its iterators and, consequently, the deque's iterators.

So it is not that chunks are reallocated, but the array of pointers to these chunks can be. Indeed, as Johannes Schaub noted, references are not invalidated.

Also note that the deque's iterator guarantees are not less than the vector's, which are also invalidated when the container grows.

Answer (score 2):

Even when you are allocating in chunks, an insert will cause that particular chunk to be reallocated if there isn't enough space (as is the case with vectors).

Comment: Reallocation is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard says it can.  It does not mandate that deque be implemented as a list of chunks.  It mandates a particular interface with particular pre and post conditions and particular algorithmic complexity minimums.

Implementors are free to implement the thing in whatever way they choose, so long as it meets all of those requirements.  A sensible implementation might use lists of chunks, or it might use some other technique with different trade-offs.

It's probably impossible to say that one technique is strictly better than another for all users in all situations.  Which is why the standard gives implementors some freedom to choose.

Comment: I dont think you mean a list (eg, std::list) of chunks, as then random-access iterators could not be O(1).

Comment: A cursory glance at one implementation suggests that a deque is more like a std::vector< std::vector<T> >, where the inner vector is fixed-reserved and never grows; however this isnt exactly right, since a pop_front from a vector would shift elements. However, a deque::iterator would really be a pair of iterators. The inner iterator never invalidates (hence why dereferences are still valid), but the outer one can go bad if the outer container reallocates. So, after a few ++iter's, you may crawl off the end of the inner chunk and have to reset to the next chunk via the outer iterator, and boom.